# How to play webm file in iOS video player

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, webm, video-player

I want to give support of webm file in iOS , but iOS doesn't support this format to play a video. i Even tried to play it through HTML5 video tag but safari doesn't support webm format in HTML5 video tag that means i also cant make it work through UIWebView. But i have seen an app that is supporting this format in their media player , that means there should be some way.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Did you find some solution for this in the end?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried integrating `MediaVLCKit` by VLC?

As per ***VLC for an iOS device***: The app claims to be able to play a veritable cornucopia of different video formats, including .*mkv*, .*vob*, .*wmv*, and  *WebM* .

PFA link for [VLC for iOS 2.5.1](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) which includes MediaVLCKit library as well.

Hope this works :)

Comment: This is working great. but taking 1.58 GB. any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a different answer in the perspective of a developer. So, if you want your video to be supported by ios what you can do is convert the video into a format that is supported by ios. Because webm format is not supported by ios currently (in iphone 15 it is supported as I got to know. that means on the iphones after iphone 15 webm may be supported but not before.)

Programmatically you have to use your backend to convert webm to mp4. Use some ffmpeg library. In node.js it is better to use fluent-ffmpeg. Below is a sample code.

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const fs = require("fs");

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

// Input and output file paths
const inputFilePath =
  "input/file/path/or/url.mp4";
const outputFilePath = "output/file/path";

// Create a FFmpeg command
const command = ffmpeg();

// Set input file
command.input(inputFilePath);

// Set video codec to libx264 (MP4)
command.videoCodec("libx264");

// Set fps (30 makes the conversion fast)
ommand.outputFPS(30);

// Set output file
command.output(outputFilePath);

// Run the conversion
command
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log("Conversion finished.");
  })
  .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    console.error("ffmpeg stdout:", stdout);
    console.error("ffmpeg stderr:", stderr);
  })
  .run();
```